# Running Stanford NLP Event parser without filesystem storage

Tags: stanford-nlp

I am currently playing with Stanford NLP Biomedical Event parser and I was wondering whether it is possible for it to not use the filesystem structure that it currently requires. I have all tokens and parses in memory already, and do not want to write them to disk in order to pass them through the Event parser. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, unfortunately, currently there isn't a way of running it without having everything loaded from disk. TODO!